# How fast can a disc read data vs a HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, disc

What is the speed that a disc can read data vs a Hard Disc Drive? Is there a noticeable improvement in load times? It would be logical that a HDD would load faster because all it has to do is retrieve the data already downloaded.

Comment: Compact disc, floppy disc, vinyl disk... What disc?  Also, what bus, and what connection to the disc drive?  A SATA compact disc is faster than an RLL or MFM HDD.  Please, you need to include some information in this question.

Comment: Also, please clarify your reference to retrieving data already downloaded.  How would that be different in the comparison you want to make?

Comment: @Everett A Blu-Ray modern disc. Sometime you'd use for a console.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming the question is referring to a DVD or CD (the only discs in many modern computers), a hard drive will be faster - although the answer would appear to pretty much all single platter disks.

Because a hard drive is almost sealed (there is an air hole which is highly filtered) the environment is well controlled, it is much faster This means -

1. A hard drive can fit a lot more data on a disk - this means more 
   information can be read on a single revolution of the drive.  [ Because
   of the density of data and the minute distance between the head and disk]
2. A hard drives spin MUCH faster - a typical hard drive will spin between
   5200 and 15000 RPM, while [a CD will spin between 200 and 500RPM](http://ths.gardenweb.com/discussions/2359126/approximately-how-fast-do-disks-cds-dvds-etc-spin) 
   and a DVD 1530 RPM.

Its impossible to provide very meaningful speed figures, because there are so many variances, but [ as an order of magnitude ] a typical hard drive will move 100 megabytes a second, while a CD will move between 1 (realistically) and 8 megabytes a second, a DVD about 10-25 megabytes per second.  Bluray disks are pretty fast at up to 4.5 - 9 Megabytes.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bit_rates) is a link of various device speeds.   Note that this is still a skewed picture as it does not take into account latencies and other factors, but it gives a rough-and-ready picture.